# Mock carrierwave using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I need to run my specs without generating the upload file.
I'm already using the clean up strategy after run specs but I would like to use a mock in order to not generate files inside the project.

I'm using:

```
allow_any_instance_of(CarrierWave::Storage::File).to receive(:store!).and_return nil
```

That code does note generate the file but creates a folder called tmp inside: spec/support/uploads

Is there a way to not generate those files and mock that store method ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance double:

```
let(:file) { instance_double(CarrierWave::Storage::File, store!: nil) }

before do
  allow(CarrierWave::Storage::File).to receive(:new) { file }
end
```

(Potentially replace `CarrierWave::Storage::File` and `:new` in the `allow` statement with whichever class name and method call gets you an instance of `CarrierWave::Storage::File`; I am not familiar with that gem or your code, but that is the general syntax for what you're trying to accomplish.)

Suggested reading:

- [Doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics)
- [Verifying Doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles)
- [File Fixtures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/file-fixture) (if you want to mock real files)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. as I call to receive :new other methods from CarrierWave::Storage::File  class don't let the code work :(

Comment: If there are additional methods you need to call, you need to define their mocked behavior in the instance double. The instance double I wrote only mocked the store! method; the basic format is `instance_double(ModelName, method_name1: method_response1, method_name2: method_response2, ...)`. If you are testing behavior that doesn't require the object be saved/persisted (e.g., to be returned by a database query), you can also try using `build` or `build_stubbed` instead of `create` when declaring your test objects (examples: https://qiita.com/Kolosek/items/ac078b9911639f8dec3c).